# JMSSerializerBundle how serializer data , Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I try use JMSSerializerBundle I updated my composer, added bundle in my AppKernel. 
And I writed this

```
namespace Surgery\PatientBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class VisitsController extends Controller{

    public function testAction()
    {       
        $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
        $serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');
        $serializer->serialize($arr, 'json');
```

And i get this

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

Any idea what I did wrong or I did't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$container is not initialized. It's a null. You need to get the container from

```
$this->container->get('jms_serializer');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this:

```
$serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');
```

to this:

```
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
```